# How to show react native <Image> with local path(not assets, it's coming from camera)?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I've been having trouble to show images in react native. How to show react native  with local path(not assets, it's coming from camera)?

P.S.

After getting the relative path. ex.(on ios, var/../../...jpg), I'm saving
that in the state and render it to my image.

this.state.path contains the relative path to the image

```
  <Image source={{uri: this.state.path}} style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}/>
```

but nothing shows.

Comment: after taking the photo, save its relative path to a state, and load it as it gets updated

Comment: yes, I'm doing exactly that

Comment: So what's wrong?

Comment: It's not showing, that's wrong. I've edited my questions

Comment: Try removing uri.

Comment: Hi, sorry, it's my fault. The uri is correct. I've fix it. The problem is the locking of file and it's not updating the bundle files. It is working correctly now.

Comment: Aha! Glad you found it

Comment: Thank you. Also, have you experienced on working the react-native-camera? I haven't found a solution to show some thumbnail and able to play it back.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I haven't tried to show thumbnails.